# is it necessary to call `enable_irq()` after `devm_request_threaded_irq()`

Tags: c, linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver

Trying to understand when one should call `enable_irq()`, and would like to know is it really necessary to call `enable_irq()` after `devm_request_threaded_irq()` call that register and interrupt handler for Linux interrupt number, and there must be always `disable_irq()` for a `enable_irq()` call?

Comment: First of all, you have to understand the difference between IRQ on IRQ **chip** and IRQ on the IRQ **source**. `enable_irq()` and `disable_irq()` just helpers to mask and unmask IRQ line on IRQ **chip** side. `devm_requet_threaded_irq()` is a _handler_ (or in terms of IRQ framework _action_) registration for the IRQ **source** in the respective device driver.

Comment: @0andriy, in a driver if there is no disable_irq(), then there should not be any enable_irq(), right ? I mean, masking and unmasking should be dealt in IRQ chip/controller driver code, right ?

Comment: It depends on what the device driver wants to achieve and why. Without certainity there is no answer to this question. You really need to talk about hardware and code at hand.

Comment: @0andriy, Okay. Also is there a API that tells if an IRQ is already disabled or not from chip side ?